# Can't create a custom class ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>

Tags: c#, generics, longlistselector

Why I can't define the LLSGroupsWithItems in the following example (it won't compile):

```
public class LLSGroupsWithItems<Group<T>> : ObservableCollection<Group<T>>
    {

    }

    public class Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public Group(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            this.Key = name;
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                this.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Group<T> that = obj as Group<T>;

            return (that != null) && (this.Key.Equals(that.Key));
        }

        public string Key
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

The compiler error is:

```
Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type.
```

Long story:

I have seen an example on WindowsPhoneGeek about how to dynamically add items to a structure of a form `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>`, but I want to encapsulte an automatic grouping functionality within the collection that my LongListSelector is bound to, so that I don't have to always look, what group to add a particular item to. For this, I suppose, I need to create a class I am trying to define, but C# limitations or something won't let me. Please explain why. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is slow as hell to start up so I'm lazy to paste this and see what error the compiler gives.

Comment: How about telling us what the error message is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
public class LLSGroupsWithItems<Group<T>> : ObservableCollection<Group<T>>
{
}
```

be written like this instead?

```
public class LLSGroupsWithItems<T> : ObservableCollection<Group<T>>
{
}
```